# Joomla Menuitem SEF url

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I am building a module in Joomla. I am using the Module Parameter (Menuitem). It returns the menu id to the default.php file in the module.

I then build a URL with the following code:

```
$itemID = $params->get( 'url' ); // Menuitem id
$application = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $application->getMenu();
$item = $menu->getItem( $itemID );
$link = new JURI($item->link);
$link->setVar( 'ItemId', $itemid );
$articleLink = $link;
```

It works correctly but the link is not a SEF url:

It is:

```
index.php/component/content/article?id=25
```

instead of:

```
index.php/call-back-request
```

How would i convert the url to a SEF url? any help would be appeciated

Answer (score 2):

You can create sef url using JRoute.
This may help you-

```
$link=JRoute::_($link);
```

for more details read this- 
http://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs

Update:

```
//article sef
$catslug = $row->catid.':'.$row->category_alias;
$slug = $row->id.':'.$row->alias;
$link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($slug, $catslug));
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i have tried that but it seems to ignore it :(

Comment: @SebastianOpperman:I have update the code please have a look.